# Call form module function from form event

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a tab control object on my form. I want a function from within my form's vba module to be called when the tab control's on change event occurs.

I have a form with a module enabled.

I have a public function in the form module named "foo()"

I have a macro "bar" that is:

Runcode: "foo()"

I get an error that Access cannot find "foo()" despite being public. If I move "foo()" to a regular module then the macro can find it. Is there a way to use a macro to call functions from a form module since it's convenient because of the "me" keyword.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/runcode-macro-action

"However, when this action runs in response to clicking a menu command on a form or report or **in response to an event on a form or report**, Access first looks for the function in the form's or report's class module and then in the standard modules."

Comment: In such a case you should better qualify it. I mean, try `FormName.Foo`. Where, of course, `FormName` is the form name...

Comment: Why macro and not VBA? You have more options with VBA (private/public access etc).

Comment: I am using an event to trigger the Macro and at least it appears to me that I can only use macros for events

Comment: Can certainly use VBA for events - select [Event Procedure] in the event's property. I can get VBA procedure outside form to call a form Sub or Function but cannot get a general macro to do it. An embedded macro associated with a control on form does work for me. As far as I can tell, what you posted should work. Although, I am not sure what you mean by **a macro "bar"** - is this a general macro named **bar**?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the solution is to navigate to the event box, click the "..." box, and then click "code builder."

This will create a private sub in your form module which you can then use to call your function.

```
Private Sub [tab control name]_Change()
    Call foo()
End Sub
```

Comment: If you select `[Event Procedure]` from the dropdown first and click the [..] button, it will take you directly to the VBA editor/ event handler. And the `Call` keyword is not required.